# VBScript DDL on Oracle 11g - Stops after DROP TABLE

Tags: sql, oracle, vbscript, adodb, ddl

I'm currently in the process of trying to migrate a series of really screwy VBScripts that are used to load data from a remote Oracle DB Source (our Vendor) into our (now) Oracle 11g R2 instance.  The script this is based on worked fine with the previous Oracle 10g instance (completely different machine), and the DDL itself works just fine when run by hand under the same user that I'm using in the CN string.

**Host OS:** Windows 2008 R2 64-bit Enterprise Edition

**Host DB:** Oracle 11g R2 64-bit

Script:

```
Option explicit

Dim CN
Dim fso, objFile

Const strOutputFile = "\\<server>\<path>\<to>\LOGS\LOAD_DATA.LOG"

Set CN = CreateObject("ADODB.CONNECTION")

CN.Open "Driver={Oracle in OraDb11g_home1};Dbq=<tnsname>;Uid=<uid>;Pwd=<pwd>;"

Set fso = CreateObject("SCRIPTING.FileSystemObject")

Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(strOutputFile, 2, True)

objFile.WriteBlankLines(2)
objFile.WriteLine "*** Start Load_Data.vbs Log - " &Now() &" ***"

Call SBB_BASE()

objFile.WriteLine "*** End Load_Data.vbs Log - " &Now() &" ***"
objFile.WriteBlankLines(2)
objFile.Close

Set objFile = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

CN.Close

Sub SBB_BASE()

On Error Resume Next

CN.Execute "TRUNCATE TABLE DATA.SBB_BASE"
CN.Execute "DROP TABLE DATA.SBB_BASE"

CN.Execute "CREATE TABLE DATA.SBB_BASE STORAGE (INITIAL 20000 NEXT 1024 PCTINCREASE 0 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 121) NOLOGGING TABLESPACE DATA AS SELECT * FROM SBB_BASE@<vendor>"

CN.Execute "CREATE INDEX DATA.IDX_SBB_SUB_ACCT_NO ON DATA.SBB_BASE(SUB_ACCT_NO_SBB) TABLESPACE DATA_IDX NOLOGGING"
CN.Execute "CREATE INDEX DATA.IDX_SBB_HSE_KEY ON DATA.SBB_BASE(HSE_KEY_SBB) TABLESPACE DATA_IDX NOLOGGING"
CN.Execute "CREATE INDEX DATA.IDX_SBB_EXT_STAT ON DATA.SBB_BASE(EXT_STAT_SBB) TABLESPACE DATA_IDX NOLOGGING"
CN.Execute "CREATE INDEX DATA.IDX_SBB_CUST_ACCT_NO ON DATA.SBB_BASE(CUST_ACCT_NO_SBB) TABLESPACE DATA_IDX NOLOGGING"

End Sub
```

When I run the .vbs from the command line, it first prompts the warning about an untrusted script (which is probably going to cause problems when trying to run this unattended from Windows Task Scheduler, but one problem at a time), and then it seems to execute without any apparent errors - but only the first two `CN.Execute` statements execute - the `TRUNCATE TABLE` and `DROP TABLE` DDL commands - nothing else seems to process.  And I know this is the case, because the table and all the indexes disappear from the schema.

However, when I take the DDL from each `CN.Execute` line and execute them manually as a block of code, they work just fine.  I can't find any error logs on the Oracle server that would indicate what the problem might be.

Any thoughts?

EDIT: After taking a breather, I figured out how to add some additional logging to the DDL statements to try and figure out what was happening - and, as it turns out, the problem is related to the `DBLINK` used in the C-T-AS DDL, as our vendor has so kindly imposed a `SESSIONS_PER_USER` cap.

However, I have a total of four different `DBLINKS` to the same vendor with different users that I can employ for data loading, and I would really like to build into the script some functionality that can check whether any of those connections are coming back with a `SESSIONS_PER_USER` message, and the first one that doesn't gets used for the subsequent data load.  Since that's a completely separate issue, I'll create a different question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Oracle person, but from the symptoms stated, it sounds like for some reason the create is being executed before some previous statement has completed, and when the drop completes, it's dropped your new table.

I'd suggest enhancing the script so that it doesnt proceed with the create until the drop has completed.

I could give you the syntax for this in SQL server, but not in oracle sorry.

Comment: As it turns out, you're somewhat on track - the problem isn't with my DDL getting executed out-of-turn, however - it's with the source of the table data - I'm running afoul of the `SESSIONS_PER_USER` cap they've employed.